# Why does os.chmod yield NotImplementedError?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, unix, file-permissions

I’m trying to use Python to set file permissions in a Unix system.

My code looks approximately like this:

`os.chmod('/foo/bar.txt', 0o644, follow_symlinks=False)`

The code works fine on macOS Monterey with Python 3.10.8.

Oddly enough, in a Linux VM with Debian 11 and Python 3.9.2 it fails:

`NotImplementedError: chmod: follow_symlinks unavailable on this platform`

However, when I try `os.supports_follow_symlinks` it does *not* throw an exception.

Does anyone understand why this happens?

Comment: What filesystem does `/foo` reside on?

Comment: When I run the program on Debian, I believe the filesystem is ext4. When I run it on macOS, the filesystem is APFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Linux man page for chmod(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chmod.2.html):

> ```
>    * chmod() changes the mode of the file specified whose pathname
>      is given in pathname, which is dereferenced if it is a symbolic
>      link.
> ```

and

> ```
>    AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW
>           If pathname is a symbolic link, do not dereference it:
>           instead operate on the link itself.  This flag is not
>           currently implemented.
> ```

and

> ```
>    ENOTSUP
>           (fchmodat()) flags specified AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW, which is
>           not supported.
> ```

So Linux doesn't support it. [MacOS does](https://superuser.com/a/1099808) - but in a counterintuitive way.

`os.supports_follow_symlinks` is a Python set of functions that support not following symlinks, it won't throw any exception because it's not a function. And on Linux, that set does not contain `chmod(2)`.

Comment: More info, from chmod(1):

     `  chmod never changes the permissions of symbolic links; the chmod system call cannot change their permissions.  This is not a problem since the permissions of symbolic links are never used.  However, for  each
       symbolic link listed on the command line, chmod changes the permissions of the pointed-to file.  In contrast, chmod ignores symbolic links encountered during recursive directory traversals`.